# Is it possible to view recently removed snap packages?

Tags: apt, snap, purge

I'm trying to remove `snap` from my system because I use and prefer `apt`. I was removing snap packages and reinstalling them via `apt` but forgot to use the `--purge` option with snap to remove any left over data.

Is it possible to get a log of recently removed snap packages so I can go back and purge them? Is it possible to purge all recently removed packages all at once, similar to `autoremove` in `apt`?

Edit:
This is `Ubuntu 20.04` and `snapd 2.55.3`.

Comment: `snap list` will show what's installed; if *snapshots* remain for removed *snaps* they could be manually removed from `/var/lib/snapd/snapshots`  (you didn't provide release details so this detail is *generic* - view https://snapcraft.io/blog/how-to-keep-your-linux-disk-usage-nice-and-tidy-and-save-space for more)

Comment: Oh, I'll add that in to OP. Thanks.